# Why does TypeScript throw an error when searching for a string in an array with .includes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

In the following example code, TypeScript throws a `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item'. ts(2345)` error.

```
type Item = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

const isInArray = (str: string) => {
  const arr: Item[] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

  return arr.includes(str)
                      ^^^
}
```

I realise that I could remove the `Item[]` type from `arr` which would turn it into a `string[]` and prevent the error, however, in real-life where I ran into this, the array is the result of mapping through some array of objects which is typed, thus resulting in the array being typed accordingly.

I feel like this should work, since we know in advance what the values of the array are, but not necessarily what the input argument is.

I guess I'm missing something. Why is this error happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It appears as though you already know why it is happening...

Comment: What does confuse me though is the fact that Array#includes is typed as includes(item: T) rather than includes(item: any), which seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a broader type than `Item`, and when an array is typed with `Item`, you must also pass an `Item`.

You have a few options:

1. Change the argument to an `Item`, as inthedark122 suggested. This way your type system ensures that you can't even call `isInArray` without a sane type.
2. Use `arr.includes(str as any)`. You're basically saying, 'I know what I'm doing'.
3. In your function, first check if `str` is an `Item`, maybe with a type guard function. If `str` is not an item, you don't even have to use `.includes()` because if `str` is something else, you already know that it's not going to appear in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript want that str should also be Item `const isInArray = (str: Item) => {`